# Make div content a document object

Tags: javascript

I have a document object

```
fetch("/something.html")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res); // logs  "#document"
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var html = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html');
    var el = document.getElementById("content");
    //set "content" to htmlDoc content
  });
```

How do I set the div's html to the parsed document *without iframes*?

Comment: What's the `res` string look like?

Comment: Yup, that totally depends on `res` string i think if it contains, head html tags or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the html you received from the API in a certain element

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
```

This will insert the html inside the given element with id `content`.

---

Please note that innerHTML attribute represent only a part of the complete HTML document. If you have another HTML page received as the response then this wont be a good idea.

Comment: I dont think this is a good idea, what if the html contains `<html>` , `<head>` and body tag so the content div is inside the body and you are putting again body inside it .

Comment: I agree, That totally depends on the response received. Also as a matter of fact the browser usually removes the extra head if exists. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set innerHTML like so:

`el.innerHTML = html;`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `innerHTML`, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(html.cloneNode());
```

If the html may contain a head or something you wish to exclude, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(html.getElementsByTag('body')[0].cloneNode());
```

If you the copy to be "safe", as in exclude scripts and any elements that are not explicitly whitelisted, you can a function like this: https://gist.github.com/mousetail/0b45eedb40adb2edc9ca18ec4a806a60 then do:

```
recursivelyCopyContent(
    html.getElementsByTag('body')[0],
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```